# XNA 4.0 shared basic effect variables?

Tags: variables, xna, shared

I'm making game inspired by Settlers of Catan. ( www.facebook.com/Expanze )
I'm optimizing my code which renders hundreds instances of same model.

```
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
{
    foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
    {
        effect.Alpha = 1.0f;
        effect.LightingEnabled = true;
        effect.DirectionalLight0.Direction = GameState.LightDirection;
        effect.DirectionalLight0.DiffuseColor = GameState.LightDiffusionColor;
        effect.DirectionalLight0.SpecularColor = GameState.LightSpecularColor;
        effect.DirectionalLight0.Enabled = true;
        effect.View = GameState.view;
        effect.Projection = GameState.projection;
        for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < validItems; loop1++)
        {
             if (instance[loop1].Visible)
             {
                  instance[loop1].UpdateEffect(effect, meshNumber);
                  effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * instance[loop1].World;

                  mesh.Draw();

                  if(loop1 > 4)
                       break;
             }
        }
    }
    meshNumber++;
}
```

In : 
`instance[loop1].UpdateEffect(effect, meshNumber);`

I change ambient color : `effect.AmbientLightColor = playerAmbientLightColor;`

My problem is that changing color affects color of earlier instances which should be already drawn.

Two images, one with if(loop1 > 4) break, the second without these 2 lines :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnfTA.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngvO2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by or nearly identical to? Hahahaha.

Likely what is happening here are your `Draw()` calls are being deferred and you're using the same instance of the `Effect` for each model. So what's happening if you're setting the values, calling `Draw` (deferred; read: not executed until later), switching models, and then setting the values FOR AN ALREADY USED `Effect` instance, then calling Draw again.

When the deferred `Draw` calls get executed they use the most recent (read: last) settings/parameters passed to the `Effect` (or something along those lines).

The solution is to create (clone, etc) a new instance of each `Effect` for each model.

There could be other issues causing this; what draw modes are you using? What are your XNA settings? This is just a standard problem people run into.

Comment: Its really only inspired - game mechanics are really different

Comment: However you are right with the problem. I solved it by changing all 3 light colors(ambient, diffuse..) for each instance. Before that I have change only ambient color in some cases.